# Unicode renders differently in python due to overlooking incorrect logic flow of two seemingly identical procedures

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I've tried to write a test() function to help parsing strings to Tibetan unicode, so I can see if my invariants are still kept when adding new features. Here's everything in its entirety:

```
import sys
from math import *

''' Translator
    Wylie to utf-8 conversion.

'''

W_ROOTLETTERS = [
    'k',  'kh',  'g',  'ng',
    'c',  'ch',  'j',  'ny',
    't',  'th',  'd',  'n',
    'p',  'ph',  'b',  'm',
    'ts', 'tsh', 'dz', 'w',
    'zh', 'z',   '\'', 'y',
    'r',  'l',   'sh', 's',
    'h',  'a' ];

U_ROOTLETTERS = [
    u'\u0f40', u'\u0f41', u'\u0f42', u'\u0f44',
    u'\u0f45', u'\u0f46', u'\u0f47', u'\u0f49',
    u'\u0f4f', u'\u0f50', u'\u0f51', u'\u0f53',
    u'\u0f54', u'\u0f55', u'\u0f56', u'\u0f58',
    u'\u0f59', u'\u0f5a', u'\u0f5b', u'\u0f5d',
    u'\u0f5e', u'\u0f5f', u'\u0f60', u'\u0f61',
    u'\u0f62', u'\u0f63', u'\u0f64', u'\u0f66',
    u'\u0f67', u'\u0f68' ];

W_VOWELS = [ 'i', 'u', 'e', 'o' ];

U_VOWELS = [ u'\u0f72', u'\u0f74', u'\u0f7a', u'\u0f7c' ];

TSHEG = u'\u0f0b'

SUPER = [ 'r', 'l', 's' ];

SUB = [ 'y', 'r', 'l', 'w' ];

SUBOFFSET = 0x50

class Translator(object):
    'Mainly modifies static variable: Translator.syllable'

    def __init__(self):
        wTable = W_ROOTLETTERS + W_VOWELS
        uTable = U_ROOTLETTERS + U_VOWELS
        Translator.first = dict(zip(wTable, uTable))
        Translator.wTable = wTable
        Translator.uTable = uTable

    def mkSyllable(self, wylie):
        Translator.syllable = Syllable(self.toUni(wylie), wylie)

    def toUni(self, syllable):
        return Translator.first[str(syllable)]

    def toSub(self, syllable):
        return unichr(ord(Translator.first[str(syllable)]) + SUBOFFSET)

    def out(self):
        sys.stdout.write(Translator.syllable.uni)

    def addSuper(self, s):
        Translator.syllable.add(self.toSub(s), s)

    def add(self, s):
        # TODO: Remove redundant join
        syll = ''.join([Translator.syllable.wylie, s])

        if syll in Translator.wTable:
            self.mkSyllable(syll)
            return

        byteCnt = self.multibyte(syll)

        # Has multibyte wylie character:
        if byteCnt > 1:
            self.uniMutate(syll, byteCnt, self.isSuper(syll) or self.isSub(syll))
            return

        if self.isSuper(syll):
            self.addSuper(s)
            return

        if self.isSub(syll):
            self.addSuper(s)
            return

        # Has singlebyte wylie character:
        Translator.syllable.add(self.toUni(s), s)


    def uniMutate(self, s, i, doSub):
        old = Translator.syllable.uni[:-1]

        if doSub:
            new = self.toSub(s[-i:])
        else:
            new = Translator.first[s[-i:]]

        Translator.syllable.uni = u''.join([old, new])

    def multibyte(self, s):
        if len(s) < 2:
            return 0
        elif len(s) >= 3 and s[-3:] == 'tsh':
            return 3
        elif len(s) >= 2 and s[-2:] in Translator.first:
            return 2
        else:
            return 0

    def isSuper(self, s):
        if len(s) < 2 or not s[-2] in SUPER:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def isSub(self, s):
        if s[-1] in SUB:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isVow(self, s, byteCnt):
        if s[-byteCnt-1] in W_VOWELS:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def tsheg(self):
        Translator.syllable.tsheg()
        self.out()

    def alphabet(self):
        i = 0

        for key in W_ROOTLETTERS:
            self.mkSyllable(key)
            self.tsheg()
            i += 1

            if i % 4 == 0:
                sys.stdout.write("\n")

        sys.stdout.write("\n")

    def vowels(self):
        for key in W_VOWELS:
            self.mkSyllable('a')
            self.add(key)
            self.tsheg()

        print

    def test(self, string):
        print string + ":"
        i = 0
        for s in string:
            if i == 0:
               self.mkSyllable(s)

            self.add(s)
            i += 1

        self.tsheg()
        print

class Syllable(object):
    'Syllable structure'

    def __init__(self, uni, wylie):
        self.uni   = uni
        self.wylie = wylie

    def __str__(self):
        return self.wylie

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.wylie

    def tsheg(self):
        self.uni = u''.join([self.uni, TSHEG])

    def add(self, uni, wylie):
        self.wylie = u''.join([self.wylie, wylie])
        self.uni   = u''.join([self.uni, uni])

def main():
    t = Translator()
    t.alphabet()
    t.vowels()
    # print u''.join([Translator.first['s'], t.toSub('k'), t.toSub('y'), Translator.first['o'], Translator.first['ng']])
    t.test('skyongs') #renders glyphs incorrectly
    t.mkSyllable('s') # this line to l.203 (print) works fine
    t.add('k')
    t.add('y')
    t.add('o')
    t.add('n')
    t.add('g')
    t.add('s')
    t.tsheg()
    print

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

This outputs:

```
ཀ་ཁ་ག་ང་
ཅ་ཆ་ཇ་ཉ་
ཏ་ཐ་ད་ན་
པ་ཕ་བ་མ་
ཙ་ཚ་ཛ་ཝ་
ཞ་ཟ་འ་ཡ་
ར་ལ་ཤ་ས་
ཧ་ཨ་
ཨི་ཨུ་ཨེ་ཨོ་
skyongs:
སྶྐྱོངས་
སྐྱོངས་
```

Apart from some stabs at duckduckgo/google, I've already asked #python@freenode, but didn't get any response. Understanding this would really be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: What should the code output, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Deleting `*emphasized text*` and running this from the command prompt, I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>`. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @Kevin: Are you running this in a Windows console not configured for Unicode output? In a Mac terminal window, properly configured to handle UTF-8, this works just fine.

Comment: Here's the output: http://imgur.com/qMx8vUX&O7eby7t

Comment: Why are you mixing `sys.stdout.write()` with `print`? `print()` will take care of correctly encoding your output for you `sys.stdout.write` may not, depending on the platform.

Comment: You should really update your question and point out the difference in the two last lines, and that it is *that* difference that is the problem here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the comment. I'm new to Python, diving in head first and having a lot of fun. I'm mainly doing this as a prototyping exercise to hash out the complexities and trying to see if I can find some structure to the problem. I'll be staying on Linux until I decide to make it cross platform.

Comment: It was on Linux that I encountered the problem, actually. Using SSH, `screen` and Python 2.6, writing to `sys.stdout` does not encode the data using the `sys.stdout.encoding` codec, instead the default `ASCII` codec is used and fails. On 2.7.5 on my Mac it all works as intended. I suspect this is a difference between 2.6 and 2.7, but still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There seems to be a lot of unicode fixes from 2.6 to 2.7. I'm on 2.7.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a difference: in your test() method, it first calls `self.mkSyllable('s')`, and then also `self.add('s')`. But in the individual calls below, without for loop, you only call `t.mkSyllable('s')` and then don't do `t.add('s')`.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the devil in the details.